# Java Mutation Testing Integration with Maven

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, mutation-testing

Our project will integrate mutation testing as part of its build cycle. Right now, we are on the evaluation phase.

So far, I have only found that Jester has a maven-plugin (Grester). I have not been able to find anything for the other mutation testing tools available (Jumble, µJava and Javalanche). Of course, we want full maven integration. We do not want to reinvent the wheel (i.e., write our own maven plugin for the tool that we choose).

Do you know of any maven-plugins for those Jumble, µJava and Javalanche? I've already googled and, like I said, have only found Grester. Also, if you know of any other mutation testing tools for java, any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: look at PIT: https://pedrorijo.com/blog/intro-mutation/

Answer (score 16):

[PIT](http://pitest.org), provides a [Maven plugin](http://pitest.org/quickstart/maven/).

It's available [from Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.pitest%22) and has the advantage of being considerably faster than Jester, Jumble or muJava. It is also actively developed and supported which does not seem to be the case for Jester or muJava.

(disclosure I'm the author and am probably unfairly biased)

Comment: You have made my day, thank you @henry - tets mutation has been on my todo list for too long.

Answer (score 3):

Of the mutation testing tools in the java world, I've found this about Maven support:

- µJava: no
- Bacterio: no (uses its own ide)
- Javalanche: no (uses its own ide)
- muTest (µTest): no
- Jumble: [yes](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jumble-maven-plugin)
- PIT: [yes](https://pitest.org/quickstart/maven/)
- Jester: [yes](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grester/)
- Simple Jester: no
- Judy: no
- MAJOR: no (uses its own compiler)

(This information was found by googling and from the article [Delahaye, du Bousquet: A Comparison of Mutation Analysis Tools for Java](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6605925).)

My vote would also go for PIT.

Comment: not seen that paper before. Do you know if a pre-print is available to avoid the paywall?

Comment: @henry not aware of such. I have the paper, I can quote the PIT-related stuff if you're interested (though it's just $13-31 to buy). It is a good comparison which I referred to in my thesis as well.